# OpenLDAP + GSSAPI/Kerberos SASL

Tags: openldap, sasl

I have OpenLDAP 2.5 configured with GSSAPI and Kerberos set up and working. By working I mean I can bind and search when I have a ticket. My question is can I do a bind when I don't have a ticket? Can I set userPassword to {SASL}userid@REALM and then bind with dn and Kerberos password? saslauthd is running and testsaslauthd works. Looking for direction if this is possible.